# Dynamics plugin - How to fetch related data

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm

I'm starting to develop Plugins, and it's the first one that uses relational tables.
If anyone can help me, I'd appreciate it!

I have the Order table, and the customer table. In the customer table, I have a column where I register the pending value of it.

Before a new order is placed, I need to verify that that customer owes anything.

I'll pass the information to make it easier to understand the code I've assembled so far:

1. Customer table - pol_client
   Pending Value Column - pol_valuepending
2. Order table - pol_order
   Lookup column - pol_nameclient

When placing the order, I need to check the customer of that order, and check in the customer table, if he owes something.

I wrote a few lines, but I don't know if it's right up to this point!
Thanks!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4rSr.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want to get Customer record by using Order record, you can code like this:

```
Entity Order = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];
EntityReference CustomerInOrder = Order.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("pol_nameclient");
if (CustomerInOrder != null)
{
    Entity Customer = service.Retrieve("pol_client", CustomerInOrder.Id, new ColumnSet("pol_valuepending"));
    // Here you did not tell about the pol_valuepending type, so I assume it is a Bool type.
    bool isAnyPending = Customer.GetAttributeValue<bool>("pol_valuepending");
    if (isAnyPending)
    {
        // Do logic as you want
    }
}
```

Please notice: your plugin looks only register on Create of Order so that you can not get Customer in `plugin context`, you can only get the created Order in  `plugin context`.